# DXL DOORS Retrieve Redlines from Specific History Version

Tags: module, baseline, ibm-doors

I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve only the redlines from a specific modification in a specific history version in DOORS using DXL?

Specifically, I want a script to retrieve the most recent set of out-links added or removed by the current user.

Psuedo-code might look like this:

```
// Loop through all displayed objects in the current module
for o in m do {

    // Loop through all baseline histories (no need to display baseline)
    for currHistory in o do {

        // If out-links were added/removed in this history version
        // break the loop because we only want the most recent version
        if ( Out-Links Were Added/Removed )  break loop

    }

    // Loop through all modifications in the current history verision
    for modification in currHistory do {

        // True if this modification was made by the current user
        if (modification.Author == Current User) {

            // True if Out-Link was added
            if (modification == Added Out-Link) {
                print "Link Added: "  The_Link "\n"
            }

            // True if Out-Link was removed
            elseif (modification == Removed Out-Link) {
                print "Link Removed: "  The_Link "\n"
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Is something like this even possible? If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make sure I understand your question- you want to see if a user has added or removed links in a specific version of a module - I assume by 'specific history version' you mean something comparable to a baseline and/or current version of a module.

Is this possible - absolutely.

How I would do it:

```
// Loop Through Objects
Object o
Module m = current
User u = find()
string uName = u.name
for o in m do {
    // Loop through history records
    History hr
    for hr in o do {
        HistoryType ht = hr.type
        // Check if link creation / deletion and history record author matches current user
        if ( ( ( ht == createLink ) || ( ht == deleteLink ) ) && ( uName == hr.author ) ) {
            print goodStringOf ( ht ) ":\n"
            print "Source Object: " hr.sourceAbsNo "\n"
        }
    }
}
```

Note! This will only handle out-links (history records of in-link creation would be found in the respective source module)

There are other history record (hr) attributes you could grab, like the date, if desired.

Does that help?

Comment: You rock. I deleted my previous comment because I found the "hr.targetAbsNo" attribute. This is awesome and close to what I am attempting to do. Just need to figure out how to loop through the baselines and find the most recent baseline where out-links were modified, and I should have everything I need. Thanks!